# Function to calculate the sum of squared deviations(from the mean) of a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, sum

I want to find a function to calculate the sum of squared deviations from the mean of a vector

```
> x<-c(16, 17, 18, 20, 16, 20, 20, 18, 18, 15, 16, 16, 19, 17, 19)
> sum((x-mean(x))^2)
> 39.333
```

A function

```
> function(x)
> 39.333
```

I want to find it also for the median

Comment: Like this: `ssd <- function(x) sum((x-mean(x))^2)` then `ssd(x)`

Answer (score 5):

Also, note that `sum((x-mean(x))^2)` is `(n-1)*var(x)`, so:

```
ssd <- function(x) var(x)*(length(x)-1)
ssd(x)
# [1] 39.33333
```

Since `var(...)` is coded in C, it will be *much* faster than the more straightforward way.